# What does the notation $\mathbf{1}\{\textrm{some~statement}\}$ mean in statistics and probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, notation

I see this everywhere but I don't know what it means.

Comment: It’s an indicator variable.

Comment: It’s the indicator function, which assumes the value $1$ on the set of all elements for which the given statement is true, and the value $0$ otherwise.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function :)